# How to trigger an event handler upon change of the field?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

Right now I have this:

```
Event.observe(
        'hidden', 
        'keydown', 
        itemOptions["_something"].showButtonsForThat
    );
```

whereas `showButtonsForThat` is `showButtonsForThat : function(){....function body....}`.

But I needed to add other event handlers:

```
 Event.observe(
        'inputF',
        'keydown',
        function() { document.getElementById('hidden').value = document.getElementById('inputF').value; }
    );
Event.observe(
        'inputF',
        'blur',
        function() { document.getElementById('hidden').value = document.getElementById('inputF').value; }
    );
```

which will change the value of the `hidden` field every time I change something in the `input` field. And now I want the first event handler (about the `hidden` element) to trigger whenever its value is changed (which changes according to whatever is in the `input` field..

I tried with eventName `'change'` but unsuccessful. Somehow using `onchange="myFoo();"` in the html element + jQuery, etc., didn't work. Maybe my syntax misplacement mistake, but I tried many things and following different examples.

**Clarification:** I want to observe the change of `hidden`, because it will change automatically when I type something different in `inputF`. So I basically will NOT interact with `hidden` at all.

Comment: You want to observe the change to `hidden` or `inputF`?

Comment: @Machavity - I want to observer the change of `hidden`, because it will change automatically when I type something different in `inputF`. So I basically will NOT interact with `hidden` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of the traditional ways worked for you, you could simply use a work-around, as bellow:

```
Event.observe(
        'inputF', 
        'keyup', 
        itemOptions["_something"].showButtonsForThat
    );
```

This means that you will still observe the `inputF` field, but will call your needed function on that. Anyway, you will call the handler on change of `hidden`, which on the other hand changes along with `inputF`, meaning that changing either of the fields happens at the same time and for the same purpose.

P.S. Better use `keyup` event name (as in my example), because `keydown` requires one more click, for the last symbol to be updated. I.e., if you type *asde* in `inputF`, then you will have *asd* in `hidden`, unless you click once more with the keyboard. And with `keyup` you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var h = document.getElementById('hidden'), 
    f = function() { h.value = this.value; };
Event.observe('inputF','keydown', f);
Event.observe('inputF','blur', f);
...
```